# Django CMS - Content only shown if on /?edit and logged in?

Tags: django, django-cms

Hello there Django folks!

I think there is some info I missed somewhere in the documentation, I have a project where I only can se the content if I am logged in.

Perhaps it's a setting somewhere, anyone have a clue where I should look for answers?

[image: This is when not logged in]

[image: When logged in]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page may not be published, draft contents is shown when logged in and published is shown for a visitor.

Please provide more details if the issue still persists after publishing as this could be that you are using an apphook or some other custom functionality.